# I need help in recovery of my project (was accidentally deleted)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, designer, resx, recovery

My project was accidentally deleted and all I have now is those three files:
project.resx, project.designer.cs, project.cs.
is there any way I can restore my project?

Comment: If you don't have any backup(s) and/or source control - then you're most likely ot of luck, unfortunately. If you had code and layout files destroyed, one can not restore those out of thin air....... Just goes to show just how important it is to check your code into source control right away ....

Comment: thanks @marc_s for the quick responde
If so, I don't see a way to restore my project... I will go to find a sholder to cry on

Comment: You'd better find a source control for yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're on windows you can try using Recuva( recovery tool )
if another OS( linux or macos) you can try using  testdisk

Answer (score 0):

First of all you shouldn't write anything in the drive where the project was located. Secondly, use a recovery tool such as [Recover My Files](http://www.recovermyfiles.com/). finally, like llya said, it always better to use source control.

Answer (score 0):

if you are having MAC OS, you can right click on your project file, click show  in finder and if you look into the bin file, you will be able to get the deleted files.